# Cant printout the result of this program

Tags: c, printing

I am new in C language and I am trying to make a program that is able to take a decimal number and print out the closest number to that decimal, However, when I try to run the program it only asks me for the decimal number and nothing else.

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num;
    printf("Enter a double number: ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    int r=0;
    if(num<0)
    {
        r=r+num-0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        r=r+num+0.5;
    }
    printf("The closest integer to %d: %d", num, r);

    return 0;
}
```

If you could help me find the issue with my program I would be very thankful. Thank you!

Comment: Please take note of compiler warnings: `scanf("%d", num);` should be `scanf("%f", &num);` Then in `printf()` you are again using `%d` but passing a `float` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your program. First of all take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/) chart, you are using variable types wrong. You are intend to receive a floating point number from the `stdin`, but you are scanning a `%d`, which is a normal integer. Use `%f` instead. This is also an issue while printing the output.

```
scanf("%f", &num); // more about the & later
```

---

Second thing, you might not get used to pointers, and memory handling yet, but if you have a trivial data structure - like an `int`, `float`, etc.. - you must scan your data, and write it in the memory allocated for your variable, so you have to pass the memory address of `num` by doing `&num`.

```
scanf("%f", &num); // you are passing the memory address of your variable
```

You can try it out by:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&num);
```

([How to printf a memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354097/how-to-printf-a-memory-address-in-c/30354164))

---

Full working example:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float num;
    
    printf("Enter a double number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    int r=0;
    if(num<0) {
        r=r+num-0.5;
    }else {
        r=r+num+0.5;
    }

    printf("The closest integer to %f: %d", num, r);

    return 0;
}
```

These errors should not terminate the program, just produce false results. Let me know if you have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few corrections in your code:

1. You are asking for a decimal number which is of type float. Therefore in scanf to read a float data type you have to use %f instead of %d which is for integer data type. The same in the last printf statement.
2. In the scanf statement instead of num you should use &num. You have to point to the memory location of the variable you are attempting to get input for.

Here is the correct code.

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num;
    int r = 0;
    printf("Enter a double number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    if(num < 0)
    {
        r = r+num-0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        r = r+num+0.5;
    }
    printf("The closest integer to %f is %d\n", num, r);

    return 0;
}
```