# What is the address of a pointer (x2)?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's take the following example where we swap the values of a and b.

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    // remember, a and be are both memory addresses now!
    printf("The address of a is: %p\n", a);
    printf("The address of address-of a is: %p\n", &a);
    int tmp = *a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=tmp;
}
```

The printout gives me:

> The address of a is: 0x7ffd36e62d08 
> The address of address-of a is: 0x7ffd36e62cd8

What exactly does the second `printf` statement tell us? For example:

```
int a = 4;
&a; // address-of a
int* b; = &a;
b; // address-of a
*b; // value-of a
&b; // address-of ...?
```

Is that just the location of the memory address on the stack?

Comment: `&b` is address of pointer variable `b` stored on the stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further expand on Deduplicator's answer, I'd change your `printf`'s to:

```
printf("The _value_ of a is: %p\n", (void*)a);
printf("The address of a is: %p\n", (void*)&a);
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354097/how-to-printf-a-memory-address-in-c) for why you should cast to `void*`).

`a` is a pointer, and has value just like anything else, such as an `int` or a `double`.  The only "difference" is, the value of `a` is an address.  Everything in C is pass-by-value, so when you pass the pointer `a` to this function, a local copy of its value is made in the function.  The pointer value is an address which points to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that just the location of the memory address on the stack?

That's correct.

Comment: is that ever used? Or not really, and is there a limit to it? For example, could someone do &&&&&&&&a ?

Comment: @carl.hiass that's not valid, try it and check

Answer (score 2):

The code should be:

```
printf("The address a is: %p\n", a);
printf("The address of a is: %p\n", &a);
```

`a` is a completely normal object, whose type is *pointer to int*.