# Number of tokens in the statement

Tags: token, compiler-construction

Number of tokens in the statement:

```
printf(“i=%d,&i=%x”,i,&bi);
```

can any one say ?

Comment: I have a doubt that bi are taken as one token or two separate tokens?

Comment: i'd say seperate tokens:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873757/calculating-tokens-in-c-statement?rq=1

Comment: Is token counting the new trend? Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 `printf`=Function (identifier),
2 `(`=ParenthesisOpen,
3 `i=%d,&i=%x`=String (template get parsed by printf),
4 `,`=Comma
5 `i`=Variable (identifier),
6 `,`=Comma
7 `&`=Ampersand (reference),
8 `bi`=Variable (identifier),
9 `)`=ParenthesisClose,
10 `;`=EndOfStatement

Comment: . float fun(char *s)
/*find a zero*/
{
   If(strcmp(S,”0”))
   return 1;
}
In this how many tokens does the 2nd line have?